# Kendo grid sort icon disappears (Angular 9)

Tags: css, angular, sorting, kendo-ui, grid

I have my project developed in angular 9 and I am using the latest version of the kendo grid. In the grid, both sort and resize columns are enabled. Everything works fine when I access the application using the localhost. But when I deploy it on the server, sort icons disappear. When I resize, it appears and disappears on hover. Any clue?

Comment: Please add some of your code.

Comment: also, since it works locally and not when deployed, be sure to check that all style/js files are available on the server and loading correctly when deployed. (use browser dev tools)

Comment: I have a similar problem in my project with and without resizing option enabled. One of my team member reached to Telerik, they insisted to share sample code block. However, the issue is not reproduced outside my project solution when I create the sample application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I tried many different ways to reproduce this issue in a different smaller Angular application so we can share our source code with Telerik.
A small application with identical source code always worked fine.
No blame to Telerik support community, I however can not share my original app code.

I attempted multiple options below..

- Debugging, console logging Telerik source
- Creating a separate application with the same grid source code that we have in our app
- Applying a similar setting for angular, package, polyfills, browserslist, tsconfig.app & tsconfig.es5 on a separate application
- Downgrading/ upgrading angular versions.
- Rewriting my grid in a different way

I gave up on this bug & I am using a CSS workaround solution below.

> search-grid.component.scss

```
 .k-icon {
  height: 1em;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'WebComponentsIcons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  speak: none;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.k-i-sort-asc-sm, .k-i-sort-desc-sm {
  margin-left: calc(1rem - 1px);
}

.k-i-sort-asc-sm::before {
  content: '\e127';
}

.k-i-sort-desc-sm::before {
  content: '\e128';
}

kendo-grid th[aria-sort='ascending'] span span[aria-label='Sortable'] {
  @extend #{'.k-icon', '.k-i-sort-asc-sm'};
}
kendo-grid th[aria-sort='descending'] span span[aria-label='Sortable'] {
  @extend #{'.k-icon', '.k-i-sort-desc-sm'};
}
```

> Since you are updating kendo grid styles make sure, component has
> encapsulation set to

```
ViewEncapsulation.None
```

> Example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-grid',
  templateUrl: './search-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-grid.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```